# link records in r with least number of steps

Tags: r, join, group-by, functional-programming

I have a dataset with 2 columns like below.

```
INBOUND  OUTBOUND
 a1         a2
 a1         a3
 a1         a6
 a2         a50
 a4         a63
 a8         a9
 a10        a11
 a50        a51
```

I wanted to give a similar id to those which are interlinked
Ex: a1 is linked to a2 , a2 is linked to a50, a50 to a51... So I would want to create a variable "id" and give same id to all these records.

I am right now doing a merge operation and marking these records. But since this is not an exhaustive search, I am able to mark only a1 --> a2, and a2 --> a50 with the same id.

So I am assuming there should be a better way to do this in one shot. 
Help needed on this. Thanks

#

```
> dat <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\Book1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
 > dat 
INBOUND OUTBOUND 
1 a1 a2 
2 a1 a3 
3 a1 a6 
4 a2 a50 
5 a4 a63 
6 a8 a9 
7 a10 a11 
8 a50 a51 
> g <- graph.data.frame(dat) 
> clusters(g) 
$membership 
[1] 
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 
$csize 
[1]
 4 2 2 2 2 2 
$no 
[1] 
6
```

The clusters(g)$membership i got is this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And the one you got for the same data is

```
1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 3 4 1
```

Comment: So are you saying you want to mark a1, a2, and a50 with the same id because a1 - a2 are connected and a2 - a50 are too?  Basically, you want to find all the disparate regions in your network?  IN this case, R1 would include a1, a2, a3, a6, a50, a51, R2 would be a4, a63, R3 would be a8, a9, and R4 would be a10, a11?

Comment: Depending on what's wanted (per Brodie's question), calculating `intersect` on all row pairs might be a start.

Comment: I added and answer that uses a c++ routine below. However, you could also have a look at the `igraph` library.

Comment: Added the `igraph` solution to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I added a much simpler answer using `igraph` below

Coincidentally, I happened to have a similar problem this week. I ended up using an algorithm from [Numerical Recipes (section 8.6 on page 345)](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) (the code in this edition contains some errors, by the way). However, the algorithm itself it is written in c++, so I hope you have the tools installed to compile this.

The code is given below. Using the function `equivalence` on you dataset:

```
> relations <- "INBOUND  OUTBOUND
+  a1         a2
+  a1         a3
+  a1         a6
+  a2         a50
+  a4         a63
+  a8         a9
+  a10        a11
+  a50        a51"
> relations <- read.table(textConnection(relations), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
> 
> source("equivalence.R")
> objects <- unique(c(relations[[1]], relations[[2]]))
> groups <- equivalence(objects, relations)
> 
> data.frame(objects, groups)
   objects groups
1       a1     12
2       a2     12
3       a4      9
4       a8     10
5      a10     11
6      a50     12
7       a3     12
8       a6     12
9      a63      9
10      a9     10
11     a11     11
12     a51     12
```

#### equivalence.cpp

The c++ file with the algorithm

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" {

  SEXP equivalence(SEXP ra, SEXP rb, SEXP rn) {
    try {
      if (LENGTH(ra) != LENGTH(rb)) 
        throw std::string("Lengths of a and be do not match.");
      int* a = INTEGER(ra);
      int* b = INTEGER(rb);
      int  m = LENGTH(ra);
      int  n = INTEGER(rn)[0];
      SEXP classes = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, n)); 
      int* cls = INTEGER(classes);
      //Initialize each element its own class.
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) cls[k] = k;
      //For each piece of input information...
      for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {
        //Track first element up to its ancestor.
        int j = a[l];
        while (cls[j] != j) j = cls[j];
        //Track second element up to its ancestor.
        int k = b[l];
        while (cls[k] != k) k = cls[k];
        //If they are not already related, make them so.
        if (j != k) {
          cls[j] = k;
        }
      }
      //Final sweep up to highest ancestors.
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        while (cls[j] != cls[cls[j]]) cls[j] = cls[cls[j]];
      }
      UNPROTECT(1);
      return classes;
    } catch(const std::string& e) {
      error(e.c_str());
      return R_NilValue;
    } catch (...) {
      error("Uncaught exception.");
      return R_NilValue;
    }
  }
```

#### equivalence.R

The code that loads the shared library (change extension from .so to .dll if you are working under windows)

```
dyn.load("equivalence.so")

equivalence <- function(x, rules) {
  tmp <- unique(x)
  tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
  a <- match(rules[[1]], tmp)
  b <- match(rules[[2]], tmp)
  sel <- !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)
  if (any(!sel)) {
    warning("Not all values in rules are present in x.")
    a <- a[sel]
    b <- b[sel]
  }
  res <- .Call("equivalence", as.integer(a)-1L, as.integer(b)-1L, 
    as.integer(length(tmp)));
  res[match(x, tmp)] + 1L
}
```

## Using `igraph`

You can also use `igraph`, which is much simpler (should have thought of that before). The groups can be obtained using the `clusters` function and the corresponding nodes/vertices can be obtained using the `V` function:

```
> library(igraph)
> g <- graph.data.frame(relations)
> cl <- clusters(g)
> data.frame(object = V(g)$name, groups = cl$membership)
   object groups
1      a1      1
2      a2      1
3      a4      2
4      a8      3
5     a10      4
6     a50      1
7      a3      1
8      a6      1
9     a63      2
10     a9      3
11    a11      4
12    a51      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you read clusters(g)$membership? I am not able to understand.

Comment: `clusters$membership` is the same as the `groups` column in the first example except that thw nummers are different. In this case the nodes seem to be ordered in the same way as in my code, but you should be able to extract the nodes from `igraph`. I don't have a computer at hand to find out how. @user1946217

Comment: hi... I am getting a different value for the clusters$membership when I read it from a csv.                                      > dat <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\Book1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
> dat
  INBOUND OUTBOUND
1      a1       a2
2      a1       a3
3      a1       a6
4      a2      a50
5      a4      a63
6      a8       a9
7     a10      a11
8     a50      a51
> g <- graph.data.frame(dat)
> clusters(g)
$membership
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6

$csize
[1] 4 2 2 2 2 2

$no
[1] 6

Comment: I am not knowing how to indent the code block in the above comment. But what I want to show is I am using the same data and same cluster() command. But it gives me different cluster$membership. How do I resolve this.the ideal output is what you got from your code. Thanks again for the support

Comment: @user1946217 Added code that obtains the nodes corresponding to the group memberships.

Comment: hi. @Jan van-I am able to map the vertices to the cluster$membership by using V(). Infact I do not have problem with that, problem is the with the difference in output you got vs the output that I have got for the same data. I have edited my question to include these observations. would be great if this is answered. I am reading data from csv, and you are doing it using a text connection. I am not sure why there should be any difference in the output

Comment: No Issues... Actually there were spaces in my input while I was reading from the CSV. Ignore my previous comment. And thanks for your support again. :)